# Write a nested doseq over unknown number of collections

Tags: loops, clojure

I have a file  `LIST` that has a sequence of characters per line.  Each line is labeled with a category, i.e. "C".  Example:

```
C: w r t y i o p s d f g h j k l z b n m
V: a e i o u
E: n m ng
```

I want to print every combination of C, V and E (or maybe just C and V, C and E, etc.) using `doseq`, but generically as I won't know the nested collections at compile time.

I.e.

```
"CV" [x y] (str x y ) 
"CVE" [x y z] (str x y z) 
"CVCV" [x y z a] (str x y z a)
```

My code `word-generator.clj`

```
(ns word-generator )
(use 'clojure.string)
(import 'java.io.File)
(use 'clojure.java.io)

(defn get-lines [fname]
  (with-open [r (reader fname)]
    (doall (line-seq r))))

(defn get-list [x lines]
  (first (remove nil?
  (for [num  (range (count lines)) ]
   (if (= (first(split (nth lines num) #"\s+")) x)
     (rest(split (nth lines num) #"\s+")))))))

(def sounds(get-lines "LIST")) ;; get the list


(def C (get-list "C:" sounds)) ;; map consonants 
(def V (get-list "V:" sounds)) ;; map vowels
(def E (get-list "E:" sounds)) ;; map end consonants
(def LI "CVE") ;; word structure 


(defn word-runner[carry args depth]
  (doseq [x C y V z E] (println (str x y z)))) ;; iterate and make the words

(defn runner[]
  ( (print "enter arg list: ")
    (def INPUT (read-line))
    (word-runner "" INPUT 0)))
```

How can I implement `word-runner` so that `doseq` does a nested loop over all sequences of characters found in the file - but without knowing the number of lines in the file at compile-time?

Comment: What does the `carry` argument of your `word-runner` function stand for?

Comment: it worked like so in C
`function(carry args depth)
if (args[depth] == args.length)
print carry + character
else
function(carried args depth+1)
`
carry simply was used to build a string but seeing in clojure there are more clever ways to do things.

Comment: You might omit both `carry` and `depth` in Clojure. The `word-runner` can be like `(defn word-runner [labels] ...)`. Then what do you expect the `word-runner` function to return. For example, `(word-runner ["CV" "CVE"])` should return a map or a vector of vectors?

Comment: it should generate the list together like so `wa we wi wo wu` etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a problem of combinatorics, not so much looping. Use the `cartesian-product` function from the [math.combinatorics](https://github.com/clojure/math.combinatorics) library to solve your problem.

```lisp
;; alternative implementation of "word-runner"
(defn print-cartesian-products [& seqs] 
    (doseq [combs (apply cartesian-product seqs)] 
        (println (apply str combs))))
```

Comment: using this code results in the following out put and I am unable to figure out how to make it work
`("w" "r" "t" "y" "i" "o" "p" "s" "d" "f" "g" "h" "j" "k" "l" "z" "b" "n" "m")("a" "e" "i" "o" "u")
nil
`

Comment: What do you mean "how to make it work?" It seems to me that you need to revise your program. Rather than port C code, you need to learn more Clojure fundamentals.